# How to create fluid html elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, typo3, fluid

How can I create with jQuery a Fluid element, like:

```
<f:form.upload property="{something}" additionalAttributes="{form:someProperty(element: element, property: 'myProperty'}"></f:form.upload>
```

I tried to write something like:

```
var input = <f:form.upload property="{something}" additionalAttributes="{form:someProperty(element: element, property: 'myProperty'}"></f:form.upload>;
$(div).append(input);
```

But it will render **litteraly** the content of var `input`.

---

In other words.

What I get now wit my jQuery:

```
<f:form.upload property="{something}" additionalAttributes="{form:someProperty(element: element, property: 'myProperty'}"></f:form.upload>
```

What I want:

```
<input type="file" name="tx_form_formframework[application][fileupload]">
```

Comment: Maybe try this: https://terrymun.github.io/Fluidbox/demo/index.html#content

Comment: thanks for the reply, but this is not exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in short: you can't.
This is because the `<f:*>` tags and `{variables}` are being processed on the server, not on the client.

Jquery could try to grab the processed HTML bits from the server via an HTTP request, but that's pretty much it :)

Comment: mmm ok. But if I want to create more `input` forms in a dynamic way? I have no chance? My goal is to create a new `input`form when the one before is used, and then send everything in backend.

Comment: You can simply create html input fields via jQuery or JavaScript. In addition you have to tell your extension that it's allowed to add new fields. By default and for security reasons it's not allowed to add some new fields via JS. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33996431/add-create-element-to-objectstorage-using-javascript-in-extbase-fluid-typo3 for an example how to dynamically add fields in extbase.

Answer (score 0):

In some situations it is possible to create the form fields via Fluid in advance but hide them until the user takes a defined action.